# Computation of complex integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Say I want to compute an integral in the form $\int_{|z|=R}f(z)dz$. What does the $|z|$ mean in this context? If, for instance, I were to compute the integral for $R=1$, would that mean that we integrate over the unit circle $|z|=1$? If so, wouldn't $\oint$ be the correct notation for the integral?

Comment: You're correct on all counts, though I would say that $\oint$ isn't always necessary. It's a nice symbol that can add clarity, but is technically unnecessary.

Comment: Okay, I was just a little confused because my textbook uses $\oint$ and the assignment uses $\int$